# Component dispatches action with old props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on a dashboard. And I have multiple dropdowns. If the user changes selected item on any of them then I need to fetch new stat data.

So I've to store the current value of dropdowns in Redux store. OnChange of a Dropdown I've dispatched new value of it to the Store. Then in App(parent) component map state to props and dispatch a stat Fetch action.

However, App component dispatches statFetch action with previous props, not the new ones. I suppose this is due to the fact that component is updating its props a bit later(https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/291).

How should I make my App component receive newest props? Or what is the intended pattern in my case?

Simplified code, parent:

```
@connect((store) => { ... }
export default class App extends PureComponent {

  handleStatRequest = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(
      statsFetch(
        this.props.viewRange,
        this.props.domain_id,
        this.props.widget_id,
        this.props.api,
        this.props.is_mobile,
        this.props.selectedCountry,
        this.props.selectedRegion,
      )
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Toolbar handleStatRequest={this.handleStatRequest}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and a child

```
export default class Toolbar extends PureComponent {

    handleChange(e, data) {
      this.props.dispatch(setDomainId(data.value));
      this.props.handleStatRequest()
    }


  return (
    <div className="filter ">
      <Dropdown onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

reducer

```
export function stats( state={
  viewRange: "7",
  startDate: null,
  stopDate: null,
  domain_id: null,
  widget_id: null,
  isLoading: null,
  errLoading: null,
  statsData: {}
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VIEW_RANGE':
      return {...state, viewRange: action.viewRange};
    case 'SET_VIEW_START_DATE':
      return {...state, startDate: action.startDate};
    case 'SET_VIEW_STOP_DATE':
      return {...state, stopDate: action.stopDate};
    case 'SET_DOMAIN_ID':
      return {...state, domain_id: action.domain_id};
    case 'SET_WIDGET_ID':
      return {...state, widget_id: action.widget_id};
    case 'STAT_DATA_FETCH_LOADING':
      return {...state, isLoading: action.isLoading};
    case 'STAT_DATA_FETCH_REQUEST_URL':
      return {...state, requestUrl: action.requestUrl};
    case 'STAT_DATA_FETCH_FAILURE':
      return {...state, errLoading: action.errLoading, errStatus: action.errStatus};
    case 'STAT_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return {...state, statsData: action.statsData};
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

action for fetching data

```
export function statsFetch(viewRange=7, domain_id=null, widget_id=null, api=null, is_mobile=null, code=null, region=null) {
  let domain = ENV === "development" ? "https://example.com" : "";
  let url = "/some/path/";
  let startStopDateRange = "?start=" + getDate(viewRange) + "&stop=" + getDate();
  let domainsAndWidgets = "&domains=" + domain_id + "&widgets=" + widget_id;
  let apiParam = api === "null"? "" : "&api=" + api ;
  let is_mobileParam = is_mobile === "null" ? "" : "&is_mobile=" + is_mobile ;
  let devices = apiParam + is_mobileParam;
  let countriesParam = code === "null" ? "" : "&country=" + code;
  let regionParam = region === "null" ? "" : "&region=" + region;

  let urlWithPrams = domain + url + startStopDateRange + domainsAndWidgets + devices + countriesParam + regionParam;

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(statsFetchLoading(true));
    axios.get(urlWithPrams, {withCredentials:true})
      .then(response => { console.log('response',response); dispatch(statsFetchSuccess(response.data))})
      .then(response => { dispatch(statsFetchLoading(false)); })
      .catch( error => {
        dispatch(statsFetchFailure(true, error.response.status));
        dispatch(statsFetchLoading(false));
        console.log(error)
      })
  };
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the linked issue is what's the problem here. There's only one dispatched action in your code sample, so I can't understand where you think there is a race condition. There might be some problem with your reducer or action creator instead. Can you add that code to your question. [mcve]

Comment: @HåkenLid I posted the code to show overall structure. Perhaps I've oversimplified it. I've corrected it.

Comment: Ok. With the updated code, it seems similar to the issue you linked. I think that a better pattern would be to avoid dispatching two actions in one event handler. If you can't combine the two actions, you might use redux middleware to add more complex effects to the first action.

Comment: @HåkenLid Would you be so kind and provide an example? I'm currently using redux-thunk for axios async request.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are dispatching the action with old props is because your App component does not update when your dropdowns dispatch their actions to update the store. So either you do not pass the corresponding state to your App component in mapStateToProps or you do not update the state in your reducer in an immutable way e.g. returning a new state object. Posting the reducer code would probably be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've updated the question, in hope of your code example.

Comment: As you already guessed, when you dispatch statsFetch immediately after dispatching the action that sets the new state, your App component did not go through update cycle yet, thus dispatches the action with it's old props. In your example you have to dispatch statsFetch with the data value from your Toolbar change handler instead of this.props.domain_id. A better approach would be to combine both actions and pass the entire set of props with the props that changed. In your approach you would have to call statFetch in componentDidUpdate for example.